# google sheets publish range of cells and protect others from view

Tags: google-sheets

i have spreadsheet:

[image]

i want to publish public part on my site. I want to protect private part from view. How to do that?

I try https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en

[image]

I add that parameter https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17OPPY3xIfMqlb-BrnGmiMjxSKCM8-4KSk6lBWpOz1Bk/pubhtml?gid=1176190046&single=true&range=A1:C3 - But user can remove it and see private data.

I try shorten URL, but it not solve problem - source url resolved when processed, parameter still can be removed.

How to protect data from view?

Answer (score 3):

I found one solution - i create sheet2 and add links to public cells from sheet1 in it. Then publish sheet2:
[image]